# Calculation of IC driver resistance, gate resistance, and inductor value

Tags: resistance, inductance, gate-driving

I want to use a [UC3843](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/uc3843) PWM controller to drive a [IRF2305](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a) MOSFET (in a Ćuk converter).

How can I calculate the resistor values for the IC input pin (pin 7) and the MOSFET gate?

For example, in the IC datasheet, the suggested current value is 200 mA. If, for example, my input voltage is 15 V, can I use Ohm's law to calculate the resistance?

R=V/I --> R=15/0.2 --> R=75 Ω

Is 75 Ω correct?

I also studied a little how to calculate the gate resistance and inductor value, but I didn't understand.

Please guide me with an example so that I can understand better. I linked to the datasheets of the IC and MOSFET as an example, but mostly I want to learn how to calculate.

This is an example schematic.
For example, the value of R8 is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Please add data sheet links to the IC and the MOSFET. Whilst you are at it you might as well post a schematic proposal and indicate whether you are converting positive to negative or vice versa.

Comment: @Andy aka - I did
thank you for your attention

Comment: Unless your input voltage is above 34 V, at which point the Zener starts to clamp, I don't see the reason to put a resistor on the input at all. Even more strange is the 34 V Zener but with 30 V absolute max Vcc.

Comment: Missing decoupling capacitor in your schematic above for Vcc pin.

Comment: A bypass capacitor-As I said before, this schematic is a bit wrong

Answer (score 0):

> *in the IC datasheet, the suggested current value is 200 milliamps.*

The 200 mA figure is not what the chip consumes from its power rail on pin 7. That 200 mA is telling you how much current the output pin was tested with when measuring its volt drop. Nothing to do with power rails.

The operating current into pin 7 is shown here in the [data sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/uc3843-309322.pdf): -

[image]

So, the equivalent resistance of the chip (as appearing across the power rail) could be said to be 15 volts divided by 14 mA = 1071 Ω typically.

> *I also studied a little how to calculate gate resistance and inductor
> value, but I didn't understand. Please guide me with an example so
> that I can understand better.*

The lower the gate resistor value the faster the MOSFET turns on but the higher the impulse current into the gate and, that current needs to be supplied from the gate driver so, you choose a gate resistor that doesn't cause a drive current that exceeds the ratings of the driver chip.

Your driver chip says it can source up to +/- 1 amp in the absolute maximum rating table so, you should keep clear of this limit. Maybe +/- 600 mA is a reasonable maximum. So, if the gate drive voltage can be as high as (say) 9 volts when driving 600 mA, it is equivalent to a resistor of 15 Ω.

I got the 9 volt value from output section in the data sheet; the power supply is 15 volts and an output voltage of 13 volts is produced when driving 200 mA hence, assuming a linear relationship, the output voltage when driving 600 mA is 9 volts.

But, inevitably, there is some residual gate resistance inside the MOSFET and this can be used to reduce the 15 Ω I calculated above. Unfortunately the data sheet for your MOSFET does not state the equivalent series gate resistance.

In a Ćuk converter there are two inductors so you need to be clear about what you are saying here and provide a schematic.

Comment: Thank you very much
You calculated the IC power pin resistance to be 1071 Ohms.
But I have seen this resistance less than 50 ohms in almost all circuits.
Even 4.7 Ohm!!!

Comment: Then, you may be measuring it incorrectly or the data sheet is lying. That is why I asked you to show your circuit. Of course if you are not using an SOIC chip then pin 7 could mean anything.

Comment: The schematic is placed

Comment: That isn't a Ćuk converter. It's input voltage isn't 15 volts either and, also on the power rail is the MOSFET and buck-boost transformer <-- they'll make a massive difference. You need to state exactly how you measured the resistance.

Comment: I thought it was a Ćuk converter.
I wanted to know how to calculate the resistance of VCC, but so far I have not seen a schematic whose resistance is higher than 50 ohms.
The numbers are only for example, when we know how to calculate, we can replace the numbers. Now with your calculation and the voltage of 12 volts, the VCC resistance is 857 ohms.
If possible, give an example of how to calculate the inductor in this circuit. (with example numbers)

Comment: Do you know how to reward someone who is trying to help you? But, I can't help you with Ćuk converters because your circuit is **100% NOT** a Ćuk converter. I can't help you with the equivalent resistance of your circuit unless you explicitly show how you measure it. I would like to answer all of your question but, there are too many errors to convince me it is worth the effort.

Comment: Thankful
You asked for a circuit to calculate the inductor. You say the circuit has a problem. Which part of it?
Where is the problem? Where is the error? I didn't design the circuit, I just wanted to learn from it.
Is the inductance calculation different for Ćuk circuits? Does it have a special formula? Is the circuit required? I'm just learning.